# Get value from list class (vector) in R

Tags: r, geography-data-type, value-list

I have a simple question about corce(?) list class data into vector. I extract a tif file from polygon to achieve a list. Maybe the class of list is leaded by extract function. I check the list length is 1, but contained 135187 number. Now I need to change the list into integer or vector. I need to calculate this 135187 number.

Comment: I voted to close but this question should actually be migrated to Stack Overflow. There is no GIS or spatial context to this question it is merely about list objects in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unclear as to what your problem is! In the future please make an attempt to provide a clear problem, question and what you have tried (along with code). Here is a very general introduction to list objects in R that will likely, indirectly, answer your question.

So, you apparently have a vector as an element in a list object. You can examine the class of the object in the list using the class function and indexing an element in the list. In the same way you can create a new object by just extracting a given element using its relevant bracket index.

When operating on list objects that have multiple elements, two important function to be aware of are `lapply` and `do.call`. The lapply function allows you to apply a function across all elements in the list (eg., mean) and do.call allows you to use a replicated function (eg., cbind) to produce a new object. Here is a quick example of working with list objects.

Create a list with 10 elements of random normal vectors with 15 values each.

```
my.list <- list()
  for(i in 1:10) { my.list[[i]] <- runif(15) }
  my.list
```

Display class, length and extract first element in the list

```
class( my.list[[1]] )
length( my.list[[1]] )
( my.vector <- my.list[[1]] )
```

Use apply to display mean of each list element.

```
lapply(my.list, FUN = mean)
```

Use do.call with concatenate ("c") to append all of the vectors in the list

```
do.call("c", my.list)
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! My problem is very simple, I have solved it.The function needed to do is unlist().Then I can coerce this list into a vector.Anyway thanks for your help!